# IP switches up on shared hosting account

Tags: ip, hosting, shared-hosting, dedicated-server

I am building a web app on a Shared server IP on GoDaddy. The app talks to a real estate API that validates the IP of the requesting server. The issue is that on GoDaddy, our IP is listed as X but it actually switches between X and at least 4 other IPs at different times. So when the IP is something other than X, our requests get turned down by the API. I'm wondering if getting a dedicated server would solve this, or if there's another way to go about this?

Comment: You can always select the interface/ip you want your request to originate from, you just have to modify your code to include the ip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can get a static IP with GoDaddy at an additional monthly cost (see the FAQs for more details): [www.godaddy.com/ssl/static-ip.aspx](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/static-ip.aspx)